# WPF RichTextBox - Language not preserved

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, formatting, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` in my WPF application, which has a `Run` in its `FlowDocument`. The XAML code looks something like this:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Bold>
                <Run xml:lang="nl-be">My name is Mark.</Run>
            </Bold>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Trying to type anything at all into the `RichTextBox`, the language will instantly change for all of the text to my own language, `nb-NO`.

This is not normal behavior. If you do the same with the `Bold`-property, anything you insert in the middle or at the end of the text will inherit the `Bold`-property.

Does anyone know why this happens? Any workarounds?

- [A working example](http://www.mediafire.com/?e9sn69a0kb2n8bw).

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot].